# Azure B2C custom policy: JWT check expiration time

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I was following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/id-token-hint). And it's working fine. I can sign up with jwt token. The problem is only, what if token is expired? How can I let user know, that he must generate new token?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by an extra field in the token in date format for storing the expiry time (not sure the existing **exp** field in the token can be used for this). After extracting the claims from token add an orchestration step to validate the expiry time against current time. Following pieces of code may be helpful.

```
    <ClaimType Id="expiry">
      <DisplayName>Expiry of email link</DisplayName>
      <DataType>dateTime</DataType>
    </ClaimType>

    <ClaimType Id="isLinkValid">
      <DisplayName>Email link valid</DisplayName>
      <DataType>boolean</DataType>
    </ClaimType>
```

Technical profile for extracting claims:

```
  <DisplayName>My ID Token Hint ClaimsProvider</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims">
      <DisplayName> My ID Token Hint TechnicalProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="None" />
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ClientAssertionSigningKey" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        .......................
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="expiry" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
```

Validation technical profile:

```
     <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-ValidateEmailLink">
      <DisplayName>Validate Email Full Profile Edit</DisplayName>                    
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />                    
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetCurrentDateTime" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="expiry" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentTime" />
      </InputClaims> 
      <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isLinkValid" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="IsLinkExpired" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Claim transformations

```
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="GetCurrentDateTime" TransformationMethod="GetCurrentDateTime">
      <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentTime" TransformationClaimType="currentDateTime" />
      </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>

  <ClaimsTransformation Id="IsLinkExpired" TransformationMethod="DateTimeComparison">
      <InputClaims>                    
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="expiry" TransformationClaimType="firstDateTime" />     
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="currentTime" TransformationClaimType="secondDateTime" />                                                       
      </InputClaims>
      <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="operator" DataType="string" Value="later than" />
      </InputParameters>
      <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isLinkValid" TransformationClaimType="result" />
      </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Orchestration step after claim extraction (probably 2nd one)

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="CheckLinkValidity" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-ValidateEmailLink"/>
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```